# php soap client, error from bad wsdl? "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host"

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm mostly new to SOAP, so I made a little test script to connect to my customer's server. They have a GetMessage command in there, that requires no input or authentication and is just intended to test connectivity:

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$url        = "https://test.mycustomer.com/api/TestService.svc?wsdl";
$client     = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

$result = $client->GetMessage(NULL);

echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
if($result->GetMessageResult->Status == "Success")
{
    echo "Item deleted!";
}
?>
```

If I run this in the command line I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/my.stage.com/htdocs/common/soaptest.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://459265-d...', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0)
#1 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('GetMessage', Array)
#2 /var/www/my.stage.com/htdocs/common/soaptest.php(8): SoapClient->GetMessage(NULL)
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/my.stage.com/htdocs/common/soaptest.php on line 8
```

And from a browser I get:

```
PHP Notice: 'SoapClient::__doRequest() [soapclient.--dorequest]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'
```

In their WSDL for this service, the string "459265" appears here:

```
<wsdl:service name="TestService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITestService">
<soap:address location="http://459265-dev1/api/TestService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService" binding="tns:BasicHttpsBinding_ITestService">
<soap:address location="https://test.mycustomer.com/api/TestService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So my question is, is that correct? Should the WSDL have a local url like that, that I can't get to from my box?

A little more info, when I do a var_dump on __getFunctions and __getTypes, I get

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(53) "GetMessageResponse GetMessage(GetMessage $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(53) "GetMessageResponse GetMessage(GetMessage $parameters)"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "struct GetMessage {
}"
  [1]=>
  string(55) "struct GetMessageResponse {
 string GetMessageResult;
}"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "int char"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "duration duration"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "string guid"
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a question to ask whoever maintains that WSDL, but I certainly think you have identified the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is wrap your code in a `try{}, catch{}` block. For example,

```
<?php
    try {
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

        $url = "https://test.mycustomer.com/api/TestService.asmx?wsdl";
        $client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

        $result = $client->GetMessage(NULL);

        echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
        if($result->GetMessageResult->Status == "Success")
        {
            echo "Item deleted!";
        }
    }
    catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

As the error says, `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in ....`, so you need to catch the exception in any case. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added that, thanks, and it returned "Could not connect to host". So I guess it's that local url http://459265-dev1/api/TestService.svc that's messing things up. I tested it on some WSDL test sites, like http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html, and those could also get info out of the WSDL, but they couldn't do any actions because at that point they can't connect.

Comment: The service that you are connecting to, should have an extension of **`.asmx`**, as in **`TestService.asmx`** and not **`TestService.svc`** as you currently have. I've also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, partially. The problem is in the wsdl service declaration, where it has two ports for the same binding (see above). In php's SoapClient, $location for __doRequest comes from the first binding (forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology), and the url for that is a local url which is inaccessible to me. So I did this:

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, "https://test.mycustomer.com/api/TestService.svc", $action, $version, $one_way);

        return($response);
    }
}
```

Extending SoapClient and overriding __doRequest, I was able to set $location to the url I knew would work. Ran it again and got the welcome message - yipee! Not a great solution, since I would have to extend a new client for each service, but to fix that all I have to do is take out the hard coded url, replace the local domain in $location with the external domain, and then call __doRequest with that, and it will work with all the services.

Comment: You can pass a "location" entry in the option array parameter when creating the SoapClient object to exactly do this thing.

Comment: You're right, Sven! Thanks, I had seen that but didn't think to try it.