# PHP Soap Client: WSDL Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying test some WSDL url and got the same error as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384515/php-soap-client-error-from-bad-wsdl-uncaught-soapfault-exception-http-coul).

As I've no prior knowledge with WSDL, after doing some search, I found that this is because the location url in the `soap:address` tag (`http://459265-dev1/api/TestService.svc`, in our case) is not reachable. Am I correct? Is this a possibilty to get that error?

Can you tell what this `soap:address` actually does? and are there any other possibilities to get the same error?

PS: The link provided above is not the API I was trying to test. It was asked to keep the original link& its contents confidential, so, I brought up this similar example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear but I'm assuming you are referring to the `<soap:address>` inside the WSDL? Normally that's where you should call the web service, but that might not always be the correct address. See some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992847/why-does-the-webservice-return-data-even-if-the-ip-address-in-the-wsdl-is-wrong/10018995#10018995).

Some automatically generated WSDL documents, like what WCF generates (since you have a .svc address I'm assuming a WCF webservice) expose the machine name as the address of the web service. If this web service is exposed externally under some domain address then the address in the WSDL resolves to the internal name of the server and is not reachable from outside so, yes, you can get "Could not connect to host" error messages.

Anything that the call cannot reach (unable to resolve the name, firewall prohibits it etc) can cause you that error message.

Where did you get the WSDL from? You had an address that ended in `?wsdl`? Strip the `?wsdl` and that's the address of your web service. If you got the WSDL by some other means from the web service provider then ask them the correct address of the web service.